# How "save_and_cli(flag)" really works?

Tags: c++, c, linux, embedded

I was tracing a piece of code for a program works in embedded Linux and encountered this. I couldn't google out useful information to show me how it really works.

This piece of code is written like:

```
unsigned char foo(*someaddress){
unsigned long flags = 0; //why use a long?
flags = save_and_cli(); //what is this?
spin_lock_irqsave(&someaddress, flags);//ok, this is a spin lock

...do something...

restore_flags(flags); //release something?
spin_unlock_irqrestore(&someaddress, flags);//release lock
}
```

It seems this LONG flags' value is never changed and what is save_and_cli() function?

Thanks if you reading this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC `save_and_cli` is an "ancient" version of `local_irq_save`

It saves the current state of local interrupt delivery and then disable it.

Function `local_irq_restore` is used to restore irq state saved by `local_irq_save`

[Here for reference](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-hacking/routines-local-irqs.html)

Comment: LOL. True, it's very "ancient". No wonder it's so hard to find some document. Thanks man. Very helpful.